# How to get the specific key pair for an ec2 instance using the aws sdk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, aws-sdk-js, aws-sdk-nodejs

I have a long list of aws EC2 instances and I would like to find the keypair associated with a specific instance. However, when I look at the AWS sdk documentation, I see there is a call `describeKeyPairs` used as so:

```
var params = {
 KeyNames: [
    "my-key-pair"
 ]
};
ec2.describeKeyPairs(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
  /*
  data = {
   KeyPairs: [
      {
     KeyFingerprint: "1f:51:ae:28:bf:89:e9:d8:1f:25:5d:37:2d:7d:b8:ca:9f:f5:f1:6f", 
     KeyName: "my-key-pair"
    }
   ]
  }
  */
});
```

which returns a list of keypairs. I can filter this returned list using `key-id` `key-name` or `tags` but I dont see a way to filter it by EC2 instance.

Is this possible to do?

reference: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/EC2.html#describeKeyPairs-property

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get all the instances that uses a specific key pair, you can use the describe-instances operation and add the filter:key-name

```
var params = {
  Filters: [
    {
      Name: 'key-name',
      Values: ['my-key-pair']
    }
  ]
};
ec2.describeInstances(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

Otherwise, if you want to get the key pair that is using a particular instance, you can specify the instance id and then read the key-name attribute from response:

```
var params = {
  InstanceIds: [
     "i-1234567890abcdef0"
  ]
};
ec2.describeInstances(params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to discover an answer to this!

`ec2.describeInstances` returns a property `keyName` which can then be used as a filter in `ec2.describeKeyPairs`